# Powershell Printer ping monitor formatting issue

Tags: powershell

I am teaching myself some powershell and as a side project, I wrote a script that will ping and monitor printers that are in my active directory. The script is working fine. but is displaying "ONLINE: " $someprinterName

I want to create a table with three columns: PrinterName, Status (online or offline).

I have written the rest of the code, but I can not figure out how to put it into table format with such two columns. I tried to put it in an array and then use: $something | Format-Table -Property .... but nothing worked for me. I am sorry, I know this is too simple, but all sources I looked into did not help me much.

code is below:

```
$printers = Get-AdObject -filter "objectCategory -eq 'printqueue'" -Properties * | Select-Object -Property *
$array = @()
Function Select-Printer {
    foreach ($printer in $printers)
        {
           [array]$printerArray += $printer.portName
  
        }
        return $printerarray
    }




#Start Processing
$newline = "`r`n"
Do {
    $downcount = 0
    $down=$Null
    #Write-Host (Get-Date)
    $hostlist = Select-Printer
    ForEach ($hostname in $hostlist) {
        if ($hostname.length -gt 0) {
            $hoststatus = Test-Connection -ComputerName $hostname -Count 1 -ea silentlycontinue
            #$array += $hostname
            $array += $hoststatus
            if($hoststatus)  {  
                write-host "Online: "$hostname -BackgroundColor DarkGreen -ForegroundColor White                          
            } else  {
                write-host "OFFLINE: "$hostname -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor White                                       
                $downcount = $downcount + 1
                [array]$down += $hostname
            }
        }
    }
    Write-Host "Down Hosts:"$downcount
    Write-host -NoNewline "Pausing "
    for ($s=0;$s -le 6; $s++) {
        Write-Host -NoNewline "."
        Start-Sleep 5
    }
    Write-Host ""
}
while ($true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to notice is that using `+=` to add elements to an array is very costly, because the **entire** array has to be rebuilt in memory on each addition.
Next, you should not ask for all properties of an object when you only just need one (in this case `portName`)

The function you have is not needed, as you can get an array of portnames in just one go.

```
# get an array of printer portnames and remove empty or whitespace only elements
$printers = (Get-AdObject -Filter "objectCategory -eq 'printqueue'" -Properties portName).portName | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}

$downcount = 0
# loop through the portnames and test if they are online or not
$result = foreach ($hostname in $printers) {
    # if you specify the Quiet parameter, it returns a Boolean value. 
    $hoststatus = Test-Connection -ComputerName $hostname -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        PrinterPortName = $hostname
        Status          = if ($hoststatus) { 'Online' } else { 'Offline' }
    }
    if (!$hoststatus)  {  $downcount++ }
}
# the `@()` makes sure $result is treated as array, so we can use its .Count property
# the surrounding `$()` subexpression resolves the value inside the string
Write-Host "Tested $(@($result).Count) printers; Down Hosts: $downcount"

# now show the result as table on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# and save as CSV file for later use perhaps?
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\printers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

As per your comment to be able to set the background color in the console printout, you can do this:

```
$table = $result | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Stream
# next loop through these lines and find lines that match 'Offline'
switch -Regex ($table) {
    'Offline' { Write-Host $_ -BackgroundColor Red }
    default { $_ }  # all other lines go in the default color
}
```

The output will now look like

[image]

---

If you also want other properties in your output, like the location of the printer, just change the above code to not only receive a list of portNames (a string array), but get an array of **objects** with the properties you need and loop through that.

```
# get an array of printer objects and remove those with empty or whitespace only portName property
$printers = Get-AdObject -Filter "objectCategory -eq 'printqueue'" -Properties portName, Location | 
            Where-Object {$_.portName -match '\S'}

$downcount = 0
# loop through the printer objects and test if they are online or not
$result = foreach ($device in $printers) {
    # if you specify the Quiet parameter, it returns a Boolean value. 
    $hoststatus = Test-Connection -ComputerName $device.portName -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        PrinterPortName = $device.portName
        Location        = $device.Location
        Status          = if ($hoststatus) { 'Online' } else { 'Offline' }
    }
    if (!$hoststatus)  {  $downcount++ }
}
# the `@()` makes sure $result is treated as array, so we can use its .Count property
# the surrounding `$()` subexpression resolves the value inside the string
Write-Host "Tested $(@($result).Count) printers; Down Hosts: $downcount"
```

<sup>Although you can expand this to get more properties in the output quite easily, at some point, the console window will not be wide enough to show the results in full and some items maybe rendered truncated on screen..</sup>

Comment: Can background color still be applied?

Comment: @Kanito That depends on what you want. A Csv file does not have color information, it is only data. If you want to print the result as table where for instance the lines for `Offline` are in red, then yes, that is possible.

Comment: Yes, I just want to display colored information on powershell.

Comment: @Kanito Ok, then please see my edit to give you an idea

Comment: Appreciate it. it works.

Comment: If I want to add a location column, wouldn't this do the job:   $location = (Get-AdObject -Filter "objectCategory -eq 'printqueue'" -Properties location).location I just want to make sure this will get me locations of all printers if they have a location entry.

Comment: @Kanito OK, I have added code for that too.